# .htaccess multiple rewriterules conflicts

Tags: .htaccess

I have some problems with .htaccess here is the code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ viewpost.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.php$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

the problem is that removing .php extension part does not work. If I move it to the top, then "SEO" links does not work. Please, can someone help me to fix this?